# Why is the R2 or adjusted R2 not used without a constant?

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit

The title basically says everthing of importance. I read several times that a R2 is not used/interpreted if one is not using a constant. My question is: why? And if this statement is valid, I would be glad for valid source because I couldnt find one myself.

Comment: Without an intercept term, $R^2$ can no longer be interpreted as the coefficient of multiple correlation.. is that what you are referring to? Or do you mean the general interpretation of $R^2$ as informing about the fit of the model relative to the mean of the response?

Answer (score 1):

Google for the "regression through origin", you'll find many links to answers, like [this one](http://web.ist.utl.pt/~ist11038/compute/errtheory/,regression/regrthroughorigin.pdf)

The basic idea is that when you run a regression $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$, and estimate it with $y=Xb+e$, then it automatically makes the estimated residuals $e$ (not true errors $\varepsilon$) orthogonal to $X$. This is neat, as you can get this equation for variances then $Var[y]=Var[Xb]+Var[e]$, which leads to an intuitive interpretation of $R^2=\frac{Var[Xb]}{Var[y]}$

If there is no intercept, then $Var[y]\ne Var[Xb]+Var[e]$, because residuals are not orthogonal to the design matrix anymore. So, $R^2$ can not be interpreted the same way.

Comment: It wouldn't be outrageous to calculate the correlation between observed and predicted responses and square it. It's just that for regressions without constants that is not the same result as usually reported for $R^2$ in statistical software.